# Confused about enhancing existing Google SPF to permit server-sent emails also

Tags: spf, g-suite

I'm using Google Apps for my domains email, and have the Google suggested SPF set:

"v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"

This works as expected.  In certain cases though, my web app sends emails to users (exim4) also.  The problem I'm having is that when the server sends emails, the SPF soft fails:

Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning xxx@xxx.com does not designate 11.11.111.11 as permitted sender) client-ip=11.11.111.11;

I'm confused how I enhance my above SPF to permit my domains IP to send emails also.  I'm not sure if I need to add to the above SPF, or create a second one.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current record authorizes Google servers. The `~all` tells SPF systems that servers not explicitly authorized should softfail.

You can either modify the SPF record so that it includes the IP addresses of your web app, or replace the `~all` part with `?all` (not recommended)

I think it would look something like:

```
v=spf1 ip4:11.11.111.11 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

However you can probably find a web page which can help you figure it out yourself: for example, there is http://old.openspf.org/wizard.html

Comment: It should be `ip4:11.11.111.11` but otherwise that's right